# Style for mobile devices

Tags: css, html, mobile

I am trying to make some of my sites more mobile friendly.  So I created a new style sheet that reorganises the pages so it is more vertical.  When I test it in Firefox's responsive design view, it all looks good.  But when I try on a phone it does not work, but just displays the site as normal which is hard to read.   I am including the style sheets like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 600px)"
      href="/static/themes/pauline/style.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="handheld, screen and (max-width: 599px)"
      href="/static/themes/pauline/handheld.css"/>
```

Is there something wrong with my media query if I want this working on an iPhone etc?

Comment: That's probably because your phone is wider than 599px

Comment: Have you defined the `meta` tag for *viewport* ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code into your html page in  section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

It will render that page with width of its own screen.

Comment: Thanks that I what I forgot, though having googleing it, I used this instead <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">